# Freemarker template: call java method and use returned string as html

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, freemarker

I have a ftl freemarker template file, I pass some object (that contains the list of needed elements) to it and trying to process html output page. The problem is that I need to implement some complex logic using this object, so if I do it using freemarkers `if's` `list` and e.t.c. it will become too complex and uneccesarry big (since I will copy same logic in multiple places on the page).

I want to render table rows depending of the size of needed elements (by key), but obviously sometimes there's no elements so I need to render an empty row too if that happens, so it's easier for me to do in java code. I know how to call a method from ftl file, my question is how do I correctly return html string for a row from my java code and put it in template so it will be rendered as html string?
For example, the row looked something like this when I was putting all of the needed entries by key in one table row:

```
<tr>
                <td>${object.getNumbers("key1")}</td> // multiple names, but all in one <td> element
                <td>${object.getNames("key1")}</td> // same, all names for all entries by "key1"
                <td>${object.getDescriptions("key1")}</td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>${object.getNumbers("key2")}</td>
                <td>${object.getNames("key2")}</td>
                <td>${object.getDescriptions("key2")}</td>
            </tr>
```

So basically it's an object that contains a List of needed objects, but now I need to print every entry from every key each in a separate row (in the example above all the entries infos were printed in one row), but I don' want to write complex logic in ftl file, because it will look something like this and I'm not even sure it will work:

```
<#if(object.isPresent("key")>
<#list object.getEntries("key") as entry>
<tr> // printing every entry
<td>...
...
<tr>
<#else>
<tr> // empty tr if there's nothing
...
<#if>
```

It already looks big and it's just for one key, so I was thinking maybe it will be easier to write something like this using java code:

```
...
public String renderRow(String key){
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(elements.contains(key)){
for(var element: elements.get(key)){
sb.append("<tr>");
sb.append("<td>");
sb.append(element.getNumber());
...
}
else{
sb.append(makeEmtpyRow());
}
return sb.toString(); // escape?
}
...
```

So I can put together needed table rows using java code, because it will be easier to implement, and then use returned html code in the page. How can I do that? I've read that the returned value will be printed as it is instead of the html. How should I call it from ftl file so it will be rendered correctly as html string?

```
... // other part of html page
<table>
#{object.renderRow("key1")} // I guess this won't work because it will be a literal string instead of html?
#{object.renderRow("key2")}
...
</table>
...
```

Also, do I need to do any special escapes before returning the string from java code? If yes, than what and how to do it correctly? I tried to search for some examples but unfrotunately didn't find anything like this case and the guides on official site are too sophisticated

UPD: I'm not going to create the whole html page out of returned java string, only the part with the table, so I will still have a .ftl file and call a method where I need to render these table rows

UPD2: Just tested it out, seems like calling ${object.renderRow("key")} works as it is and actually takes the returned string as an html code. But from java code I'm returning `sb.toString()` and not doing any escapes, is it enough and ftl does something for me with escaping or I need to manually escape returned html string, if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was easier than I expected. You can make a call from .ftl file to java method which will return a rendered html code like this:

```
#{object.renderRow("key1")}
```

Just make sure that returned string is escaped so the data won't be lost, in my example I escaped the data in the `td` tags, i.e:

```
public String renderRow(String key){
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(elements.contains(key)){
for(var element: elements.get(key)){
sb.append("<tr>");
sb.append("<td>");
sb.append(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(element.getNumber()));
...
}
else{
sb.append(makeEmtpyRow());
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

At the end I got a page with the needed amount of `<tr>`s and `<td>`s and the data was properly displayed (even if there are special html symbols like `<` in the data).

Comment: This implies that you have auto-escaping off, which is not recommended.

Comment: Also, probably you have taken over number formatting from FreeMarker there, or I guess that's what `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape` will do if its argument is a number.

Answer (score -1):

You should always use auto-escaping, so that `String`-s by default are HTML-escaped. See: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html

Then, where you return a `String` that's actually HTML, like `"This is <em>HTML</em>!"`, use `HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE.fromMarkup("This is <em>HTML</em>!")` instead of a `String`. Then when it's printed with `${}`, FreeMarker will know that it needs no escaping.

Comment: I have absoutely no idea what are you talking about, what html auto escaping, how do I use it? Put `HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE.fromMarkup` where? What data model? Can you provde more understandable answer?

Comment: then you shouldn't be writing "answers" if you're linking your every word to "documentation", I provided a detailed question and expect an understandable answer, sorry, not everyone is familiar with every technology like you expect them to, I'm going to flag your answer for being useless

Comment: and I'm not going to make a whole html page out of returned java code, only a part of it, so your "fromMarkup" is irrelevant here too

Comment: @Arzybek Like `object.renderRow("key1")` should return `formMarkup`-ed `String`, insetad of just a `String`. That's only one piece of your output, not the whole output. You can also tell on template side what's already HTML via `someString?no_esc`, but I think that's less manageable.

Comment: lol, how do you know it was me, I saw it was -2 too, anyways your answer is not helpful at all, that's the point of so, to help people, I've already provided enough info and proofs of my own work, I came here to ask, not to argue with people who's answering but not really answering questionsю And the question was -1 moments before I posted it, so I assume you -1 ed it after you "answered", why would you do that, if you're trying to help? Funny

Comment: @Arzybek I assumed people who find this the question want to know how to return a piece of HTML from Java (through the data-model, like via a Java method return value), and avoid it being escaped. Or maybe, how to make non-HTML `String`-s escaped. And my answer was/is: Use auto-escaping (best practice), and then use `fromMarkup` to avoid escaping if something is already HTML. Updated my answer with direct link about auto-escaping. Is it clear now?

Comment: absoutely not, you made it too complex for no reason, but don't worry, I already found the simple answer and will post it in order to actually help other people

Comment: @Arzybek If you believe that there's "no reason" for using auto-escaping... It's security by default. Also, it's generally not simpler to escape every non-HTML string on the Java side, compared to marking HTML as already escaped on the Java side, as most strings coming from the data-model in most applications are non-HTML.